# How to get the order of SubRollouts in MaxScript

Tags: maxscript

I'm trying to access a property of the `mainSubRollout` for the order the sub rollouts are in.

After running the code below and dragging Sub 2 rollout to the top like the image and checking `mainRolTest.mainSubRollout.rollouts` it always returns `#(Rollout:subRollout1, Rollout:subRollout2)` even though the displayed order of the rollouts are not the same.

[image]

How can I access this order in which they are currently displayed?

A result for the image should be: `#(Rollout:subRollout2, Rollout:subRollout1)`

```
try destroyDialog mainRolTest catch()

(

  rollout subRollout1 "Sub 1" autoLayoutOnResize:true
  (
    button theButton1 "Fake Button 1"
    )

  rollout subRollout2 "Sub 2"  autoLayoutOnResize:true
  (
    button theButton2 "Fake Button 2"
    )

  rollout mainRolTest "..."
  (

    button btn_close "X" align:#right offset:[13,-5]

    SubRollout mainSubRollout "" height:133 width:150 pos:[0,20]

    on btn_close pressed do destroydialog mainRolTest

    )

  createDialog mainRolTest 150 133 style:#() lockHeight:true lockWidth:true
  AddSubRollout mainRolTest.mainSubRollout subRollout1
  AddSubRollout mainRolTest.mainSubRollout subRollout2

  )

-- This always returns #(Rollout:subRollout1, Rollout:subRollout2)
-- Even though the order of the rollouts are not the same
-- How can i access this info?
mainRolTest.mainSubRollout.rollouts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use their actual position:

```
fn sortByY A B = (windows.getWindowPos A.hWnd).y - (windows.getWindowPos B.hWnd).y
rollouts = #() + mainRolTest.mainSubRollout.rollouts
qSort rollouts sortByY --> 'rollouts' will now be sorted based on Y
```

If you want the index and don't mind a bit of .NET, it can also be done this way:

```
iGlobal = (dotNetClass "Autodesk.Max.GlobalInterface").Instance
rollupContainer = iGlobal.GetIRollup (UIAccessor.GetParentWindow mainRolTest.mainSubRollout.rollouts[1].hwnd)
rollupContainer.GetPanelIndex mainRolTest.mainSubRollout.rollouts[2].hwnd
```

For completeness sake, you can do it through the Qt, too:

```
QtWidgets = python.import "PySide2.QtWidgets"
rolloutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget.find (UIAccessor.GetParentWindow mainRolTest.mainSubRollout.rollouts[1].hwnd)
((rolloutWidget.parent()).layout()).indexOf rolloutWidget
```

Comment: Strange how there's no built-in method to get that. I wonder how those rollouts in the render dialog etc. remember their positons. Thanks this will allow me to read an ini file and open the dialog in their last positions based on that array.

Comment: Well, the indices _are_ stored and exposed if you're using the SDK, so technically you can retrive them in maxscript, too - I've edited the answer to show that.

Comment: Thanks, Swordslayer. The .NET method will probably be the method I'll use.